# reading character like ö and ü from file in eclipse

Tags: java, file-io

I have a input file which contains some words like *bört and übuk*.When I read this line  based on the following code I got these strange results. How can I solve it?

```
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
      if (line == null) { break; }
      String[] words = line.split("\\W+");
      for (String word : words) {
          System.out.println(word);
```

output is

```
b
rt
and
buk
```

Comment: You'll have to change how you construct your `BufferedReader` to read with the proper encoding.

Comment: How should I read encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your problem is that standard character class `\\W` is negation of `\\w` which represents only `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` characters, so `split("\\W+")` will split on every character which is not in this character class like in your case `ö`, `ü`.

To solve this problem and include also Unicode characters you can compile your regex with `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag which enables the Unicode version of Predefined character classes and POSIX character classes. To use this flag you can add `(?U)`at start of used regex

```
String[] words = line.split("(?U)\\W+");
```

Demo:

```
String line = "bört and übuk";
String[] words = line.split("(?U)\\W+");
for (String word : words) 
      System.out.println(word);
```

Output:

```
bört
and
übuk
```

Comment: but my output is: 'bÃ
rt
and
Ã
buk'                                                                 should I change the setting my file that I read from.

Comment: In that case my answer is solution to your different problem. If you are getting different characters then written in file then it means that you did not use same encoding in reader as encoding of file. Take a look at slaadvaks answer to see how you can change encoding of reader.

Comment: @user3586943 Also `my output is: 'bÃ rt and Ã buk'` should be part of your original question so we would know what problem you are actually trying to solve. You should [[edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23702687/edit)] your question and place all relevant informations about your situation like encoding used in your file, encoding of eclipse project, how did you create your reader.

Comment: @Pshemo - Why would that be in the original question?  The output only became `bÃ rt and Ã buk` when the OP tried your solution.

Comment: I create new file in my eclipse then I copy the line and I got the correct result. Thank you Pshemo

Comment: @DavidWallace I assumed that OP would get this result from `readLine()` which exist in original question. But you are probably right, OP could also not check what data (s)he is trying to split and see this problem after using my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a `BufferedReader` handling UTF8 characters encoding :

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("someFile.txt"));
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

Comment: These days, instead of passing the string `"UTF-8"` to your `InputStreamReader`, you could use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` and not have to deal with the `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

Comment: @ slaadvak, The suggestion code does not change the output.

Comment: I do not know I only create a file in my eclipse and write the line, How should I find it?

Comment: There are no proven ways of determining the character encoding of a file. You should check how the file has been created instead (check for the editor settings, for example)

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this :-

```
BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF-8"));
```

Here instead of `UTF-8` , you can put the encoding you need to support while reading the file